# How to highlight variables in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

How to highlight variables in sublime text 3? like in netbeans

[image: Netbeans]

[image: Sublime text 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but here are some options. First, if you're just trying to get variables highlighted differently, you'll need a color scheme with more options than the default Monokai. There are many available on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme), but one in particular that I know will work (since I'm its author) is [Neon](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme):

[image: Neon]

You can use the excellent [tmTheme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Neon) to see how this or hundreds of other themes will look (sort of) in different languages. (I say "sort of" because the highlighting engine used on the website is different than the one in Sublime, so there will be some differences. Overall it's pretty good, though.)

On the other hand, if you're trying to highlight all the instances of the `$page` variable, you'll have to do two things. First, double-click on `$page` to select it. Then, select **`Find -> Quick Find All`** (or use its keyboard shortcut) to select all the instances of `$page` in the document:

[image: Quick Find All - PHP]

<sup>*The gutter icons and colored underlines are from the [BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin*</sup>

Unfortunately, this is the only way to get this to work when using PHP and other languages like JavaScript that denote variables with a `$` or other symbol. If we were to use Python, for example, you could just double-click on `page` and it would look like so:

[image: Python]

As you can see, all the other instances of `page` have boxes around them. This behavior is hard-coded into Sublime, so while it can be turned on and off, it can't be modified or told to recognize other characters in any way.

Good luck!

Comment: I am using Word​Highlight but i does not take $ and it does not have a background color, do you know how i can fix that, that i can get it like in netbeans with a single click?  https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WordHighlight